# Where is this singleton included from?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I recently inherited some IOS app code containing a singleton static objective C class that contains the data shared between various classes in the app. It is very nifty design pattern and I have already taken advantage of it for my additions to the code. The structure of the singleton is very similar to this [post](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/)

There is just one thing about it that sort-of freaks me out. None of the Objective C Objects that use this singleton import its header file; but they all have access to it's implementation declared interface. This looks a little like "spooky interactions from a distance" to me. Type the name of the singleton and xcode helpfully suggests completions for your code statement. When compiled the compiler, smiles on and never complains about a missing declaration.

Yes, I have checked for imports that import the header, none of them do. I made a simple test class that only included its own header yet there in the methods I can place the singleton's name and access anything in it.

So my question is who or what is doing this automatic import? Xcode? Objective C? Little green aliens?

Comment: Is it included in the `.pch` file?

Comment: What Brian said, you will most likely find it in your projects pre-compiled header. It should be in the Supporting Files group with a name like `<project-name>-Prefix.pch`.

Comment: You nailed it Brian, want to phrase it as an answer? I'd happily check you.

Comment: Also, being that pch is a generated file, any chance it will be re-generated in the project's lifetime?

Comment: It'll be regenerated when you modify the .pch, or when you clean the project (⌘K)

Comment: Cyrille,, I checked this, the application's pch source file is not re-generated on a clean. Perhaps you meant that the object code is regenerated?

Answer (score 0):

Its in there somewhere, you can use

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n -H "Beer.h" {} \;
```

in your projects directory, where Beer.h is the filename of your Singleton.

Comment: ... or just Xcode "search navigator" (⌘3), looking for `Beer.h`

Comment: add a -r to that grep Pétur and you don't need the find

Comment: No @gjpc find provides the list of files in all subdirectories to grep.

Comment: True, but `grep -r "Beer.h" *` does just the same.

Comment: I tried searching for Beer in my Xcode and didn't find any.  What am I missing?

Comment: @HotLicks All the fun.

Comment: @HotLicks: I think you need to fax a scan of your driver license to Apple first and wait 2-3 weeks for them to check it.

Comment: Enough to make one want to break out of jail.